# pygame2exe module not iterable

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

I am using the py2exe script found on the pygame site ([here](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe)) to compile a simple program that only uses sys and pygame. When I run it, I get this error:

```
running py2exe
creating C:\Users\python2.6\Desktop\build
creating C:\Users\python2.6\Desktop\build\bdist.win32
creating C:\Users\python2.6\Desktop\build\bdist.win32\winexe
creating C:\Users\python2.6\Desktop\build\bdist.win32\winexe\collect-2.6
creating C:\Users\python2.6\Desktop\build\bdist.win32\winexe\bundle-2.6
creating C:\Users\python2.6\Desktop\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp
creating C:\Users\python2.6\Desktop\dist
*** searching for required modules ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\python2.6\Desktop\pyg2exe.py", line 170, in <module>
    BuildExe().run() #Run generation
  File "C:\Users\python2.6\Desktop\pyg2exe.py", line 161, in run
    dist_dir = self.dist_dir
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1306, in find_needed_modules
    mf.import_hook(f)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 181, in find_head_package
    if '.' in name:
TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable
```

here is the pygame2exe code:

```
# This will create a dist directory containing the executable file, all the data
# directories. All Libraries will be bundled in executable file.
#
# Run the build process by entering 'pygame2exe.py' or
# 'python pygame2exe.py' in a console prompt.
#
# To build exe, python, pygame, and py2exe have to be installed. After
# building exe none of this libraries are needed.
#Please Note have a backup file in a different directory as if it crashes you 
#will loose it all!(I lost 6 months of work because I did not do this)


try:
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe, pygame
    from modulefinder import Module
    import glob, fnmatch
    import sys, os, shutil
    import operator
except ImportError, message:
    raise SystemExit,  "Unable to load module. %s" % message

#hack which fixes the pygame mixer and pygame font
origIsSystemDLL = py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL # save the orginal before we edit it
def isSystemDLL(pathname):
    # checks if the freetype and ogg dll files are being included
    if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in ("libfreetype-6.dll", "libogg-0.dll","sdl_ttf.dll"): # "sdl_ttf.dll" added by arit.
            return 0
    return origIsSystemDLL(pathname) # return the orginal function
py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL = isSystemDLL # override the default function with this one

class pygame2exe(py2exe.build_exe.py2exe): #This hack make sure that pygame default font is copied: no need to modify code for specifying default font
    def copy_extensions(self, extensions):
        #Get pygame default font
        pygamedir = os.path.split(pygame.base.__file__)[0]
        pygame_default_font = os.path.join(pygamedir, pygame.font.get_default_font())

        #Add font to list of extension to be copied
        extensions.append(Module("pygame.font", pygame_default_font))
        py2exe.build_exe.py2exe.copy_extensions(self, extensions)

class BuildExe:
    def __init__(self):
        #Name of starting .py
        self.script = "Hello.py"

        #Name of program
        self.project_name = "Hello.py"

        #Project url
        self.project_url = "about:none"

        #Version of program
        self.project_version = "0.0"

        #License of the program
        self.license = "MyApps License"

        #Auhor of program
        self.author_name = "Me"
        self.author_email = "example@example.com"
        self.copyright = "Copyright (c) 2009 Me."

        #Description
        self.project_description = "MyApps Description"

        #Icon file (None will use pygame default icon)
        self.icon_file = None

        #Extra files/dirs copied to game
        self.extra_datas = []

        #Extra/excludes python modules
        self.extra_modules = [sys,pygame]
        self.exclude_modules = []

        #DLL Excludes
        self.exclude_dll = ['']
        #python scripts (strings) to be included, seperated by a comma
        self.extra_scripts = []

        #Zip file name (None will bundle files in exe instead of zip file)
        self.zipfile_name = None

        #Dist directory
        self.dist_dir ='Hellodir'

    ## Code from DistUtils tutorial at http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial
    ## Originally borrowed from wxPython's setup and config files
    def opj(self, *args):
        path = os.path.join(*args)
        return os.path.normpath(path)

    def find_data_files(self, srcdir, *wildcards, **kw):
        # get a list of all files under the srcdir matching wildcards,
        # returned in a format to be used for install_data
        def walk_helper(arg, dirname, files):
            if '.svn' in dirname:
                return
            names = []
            lst, wildcards = arg
            for wc in wildcards:
                wc_name = self.opj(dirname, wc)
                for f in files:
                    filename = self.opj(dirname, f)

                    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, wc_name) and not os.path.isdir(filename):
                        names.append(filename)
            if names:
                lst.append( (dirname, names ) )

        file_list = []
        recursive = kw.get('recursive', True)
        if recursive:
            os.path.walk(srcdir, walk_helper, (file_list, wildcards))
        else:
            walk_helper((file_list, wildcards),
                        srcdir,
                        [os.path.basename(f) for f in glob.glob(self.opj(srcdir, '*'))])
        return file_list

    def run(self):
        if os.path.isdir(self.dist_dir): #Erase previous destination dir
            shutil.rmtree(self.dist_dir)

        #Use the default pygame icon, if none given
        if self.icon_file == None:
            path = os.path.split(pygame.__file__)[0]
            self.icon_file = os.path.join(path, 'pygame.ico')

        #List all data files to add
        extra_datas = []
        for data in self.extra_datas:
            if os.path.isdir(data):
                extra_datas.extend(self.find_data_files(data, '*'))
            else:
                extra_datas.append(('.', [data]))

        setup(
            cmdclass = {'py2exe': pygame2exe},
            version = self.project_version,
            description = self.project_description,
            name = self.project_name,
            url = self.project_url,
            author = self.author_name,
            author_email = self.author_email,
            license = self.license,

            # targets to build
            windows = [{
                'script': self.script,
                'icon_resources': [(0, self.icon_file)],
                'copyright': self.copyright
            }],
            options = {'py2exe': {'optimize': 2, 'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True, \
                                  'excludes': self.exclude_modules, 'packages': self.extra_modules, \
                                  'dll_excludes': self.exclude_dll,
                                  'includes': self.extra_scripts} },
            zipfile = self.zipfile_name,
            data_files = extra_datas,
            dist_dir = self.dist_dir
            )

        if os.path.isdir('build'): #Clean up build dir
            shutil.rmtree('build')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if operator.lt(len(sys.argv), 2):
        sys.argv.append('py2exe')
    BuildExe().run() #Run generation
    raw_input("Press any key to continue") #Pause to let user see that things ends
```

and here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

# set up pygame
pygame.init()

# set up the window
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello world!')

# set up the colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# set up fonts
basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up the text
text = basicFont.render('Hello world!', True, WHITE, BLUE)
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
textRect.centery = windowSurface.get_rect().centery

# draw the white background onto the surface
windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

# draw a green polygon onto the surface
pygame.draw.polygon(windowSurface, GREEN, ((146, 0), (291, 106), (236, 277), (56, 277), (0, 106)))

# draw some blue lines onto the surface
pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (60, 60), (120, 60), 4)
pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (120, 60), (60, 120))
pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLUE, (60, 120), (120, 120), 4)

# draw a blue circle onto the surface
pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, BLUE, (300, 50), 20, 0)

# draw a red ellipse onto the surface
pygame.draw.ellipse(windowSurface, RED, (300, 250, 40, 80), 1)

# draw the text's background rectangle onto the surface
pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, (textRect.left - 20, textRect.top - 20, textRect.width + 40, textRect.height + 40))

# get a pixel array of the surface
pixArray = pygame.PixelArray(windowSurface)
pixArray[480][380] = BLACK
del pixArray

# draw the text onto the surface
windowSurface.blit(text, textRect)

# draw the window onto the screen
pygame.display.update()

# run the game loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

I am hoping to use this to figure out how to better use pygame2exe so I can then use it on a more complicated program.

Comment: You're going to have to show your code if you want help.

Comment: you can try http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to specify that you are using the pygame module under the BuildExe.**init** function.

Comment: I had just recently started wondering if that might have caused it, Thanks for confirming it!